# mail function in php not sending headers

Tags: php, mysqli

I brought a shared sever, and got a little storage space. When i run my web site, the mail function works perfectly. Mail has been sent with subject and message to all receivers. But the mail which is sent mentioned "From : ". Headers what i included are not working.
I want to send with my headers Eg:Form: mymail@mysite.com . How can i do it?

```
<?php
$output="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $sub=$_POST['subject'];
    $msg=$_POST['message'];
    $sql = "select email from login where status='client'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $to=array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $to[] = $row['email'];
        $parts = implode(',',$to);
        $headers = 'From: mymail@mysiet.com;';
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $subject = $sub;
        $content = $msg;    
    }

    if(mail($parts,$subject,$content,$headers))
    {
        $output="mail sent";
    }
    else
    {
        $output="Error in connection, Mail could not be sent. Please try again";
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually specify the headers, this is the function I use and it delivers to pretty much every provider beautifully. The headers you want are `From:` and `Reply-To:` and I also advise the `X-Mailer` follows what is seen here, I found it years ago via SO as well.

```
<?php
    $to      = "user@anotherdomain.com";                                
    $headers = 'From: My Name <email@domain.com.au>' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: My Name <email2@domain.com.au>' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
               'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
    $subject = "My subject line here";
    $message = 'Message HTML and Content Here.';

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        // Success Here
    }else{
        // Failed Here
    }
?>
```

I am not 100% certain it will work for you as I am on a dedicated machine, having said that - I do use it on multiple domains and have never messed with my Apache or php configuration in relation to mail settings.

Read More about the Mail function in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: BCC is simply another line within the headers variable, except instead of `'From: '` you will put `'Bcc: '` - It is of my understanding that these are CASE sensitive. CC is the same `'Cc: '` (I have updated my answer to include a link to the PHP documentation on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, just ripped from php.net

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Off topic but good to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).